xUnit tests using TestContainers failing in GitHub Actions
I've written integration tests in a C# xUnit test project and use Testcontainers for managing the dependencies (such as Postgres) in Docker containers. When I run my tests locally with dotnet test everything works just fine. The containers are automaticly being started and being stopped.
However, in GitHub Actions I receive this error for each test:
[xUnit.net 00:00:55.13]     IntegrationTests.MessageExchangeTests.TestLikeServiceSendsMessage [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:55.13]       Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException : Docker API responded with status code=Conflict, response={"message":"Container 46496d12b6c11c2c43edb96301bbfa1c9ddde217c0c54bb22e3a72ef8e479fb5 is not running"}

Extra information:
[testcontainers.org 00:00:00.07] Connected to Docker:
  Host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  Server Version: 24.0.9
  Kernel Version: 6.5.0-1018-azure
  API Version: 1.43
  Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
  Total Memory: 15.61 GB

GitHub Workflow:
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x

  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

  integration-test:
    name: Integration Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
      
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x

      - name: Check Docker version
        run: docker --version
      - name: Start Docker
        run: sudo service docker start
      - name: Restore dependencies for Integration Tests
        run: dotnet restore ./IntegrationTests
      - name: Build Integration Tests
        run: dotnet build ./IntegrationTests --no-restore
      - name: Run Integration Tests
        run: dotnet test ./IntegrationTests --no-build --verbosity normal

How can this be fixed?

I'm using host.docker.internal which is why it's working locally on Mac, however this is not available in Linux (Github Actions). What would be an alternative? I tried 172.17.0.1 but it doesn't work.

Did you get this working? I'm getting the exact same error.
